# How to count number of occurence in a function using python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a function that generates a match pattern each time. I want to count the number of time a given matching pattern has occurred
each time the function run and gives me a match pattern, using my function below i cant and i do not understand why I can not count each occurrence of a given pattern.

```
countp = 0                                  
if re.match(a, b):
    match = re.match(lines, bob)
    match1 = match.group()


    countp = countp + 1
print countp
```

Comment: This is because you are resetting the countp to 0 everytime the function is run

Comment: thanks it works when the counter is outside the loop

Comment: if my answer helped, would you mind accepting it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, try using the `global` indicator:

```
count = 0:

def some_method():
    global count
    count += 1
    print count

>>> some_method()
1
>>> some_method()
2
>>> some_method()
3
>>> some_method()
4
```

Comment: i'll try this too..tnx for reply